# Why next button open and close my calendar?

Tags: jquery-ui, calendar, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using two datepickers in my project, start date and end date. 
The first one open the second calendar with **show** method.

I notice the **next** button on the second calendar close and reopen the calendar.
I want to avoid this "open/reopen" issue.

What am i doing wrong ?

**HTML**

```
<input id="startDate" type="text" /><br />
<input id="endDate" type="text" /><br />
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function(){
    $('#startDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
            $('#endDate').datepicker("show");
        }
    });

    $('#endDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });

});
```

Please check my code : http://jsfiddle.net/8w8v9/3078/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a dirty solution, I can only suppose what happen: you show the "endDate" datepicker before is totaly closed the first one and this creates some conflict.

[The JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8w8v9/3080/)

```
$(function() {

  $('#startDate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#endDate').datepicker('show');
      }, 50);
    }
  });

  $('#endDate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
  });

});
```

Comment: Yes i will accept this answer. I solve it too by doing this way. But for the delay i put 0